# Naming a class' self a variable name

Tags: python, class

Is it possible to use the name of an input, eg a yaml/dict key, on self while not knowing that key literally?

Meaning, if there were some data like:

```
entries = [
    {'foo': 'foo 1', 'bar': 'bar 1'},
    {'foo': 'foo 2', 'bar': 'bar 2'},
]
```

How could we do the below without explicitly preprogramming 'foo' and 'bar' to name the self variables?

```
class entry(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = entries[0]['foo']
        self.bar = entries[0]['bar']
```

And I suppose those self assignments would not have to be named foo and bar, but at least be able to reference them as such.

Comment: You can use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) function. for example `setattr(self, 'foo', 'entries[0]['foo']')` is equivalent to `self.foo = entries[0]['foo']`

Comment: I believe I understand what you want to do, but that's not a good design. Classes, by definition, should serve as a "contract" - it should have attributes such that whomever calls those classes/instantiate objects know what to expect. A class that has totally unpredictable attributes is useless - how will anyone know what object to use? If you want a dynamic data structure that is _mutable_, and that holds different "attributes" at different points in time, you need exactly a `dict`. Instead of using `obj.foo`, you'd call `my_dict['foo']` - so I'd just stick to your `entries` dictionaries

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in function [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) to add/set an attribute on an object in Python

```
def __init__(self):
    for k, v in entries[0].items():
        setattr(self, k, v)
```

Comment: This helped me a ton. I have also used `if hasattr(self, k):` prior to using `setattr()` as well to catch instances (in the else clause) where an invalid key may be passed through to the class.